# HIVE - ALTER TABLE my_table CLUSTERED BY (my_field) INTO 32 BUCKETS - apply retroactively?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is there a way to reorganize/reformat the data to be bucketed retroactively using the above statement?
Insertion being made after the ALTER statement are indeed being bucketed.. but I want the data to be changed backwards as well.

From the manual:
"NOTE: These commands will only modify Hive's metadata, and will NOT reorganize or reformat existing data. Users should make sure the actual data layout conforms with the metadata definition."

How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These steps should do the trick:

1. Create a new table with the right structure
2. Insert all your data into it
3. Replace the old table with the new table

Maybe there is a way to mess around with the existing table, but these steps should be safer than that.

Comment: If I don't change format of existing data , it's just that performance will be affected right? But I will still be able to query the old data even after changing clustering of an existing hive table?

Comment: @Dhiraj we should not go too deep into it in the comments (if needed you can ask a separate question). But i would indeed say this changes 'which row lives where' which should only be nonfunctional. All select queries you have will work. Not sure if there is any impact on the insert.